# uploading files greater than 8 mb in php

Tags: php, mysql

> Warning: POST Content-Length of 11313557 bytes exceeds the limit of
>   8388608 bytes

I am getting this above warning.  I searched around internet and I have also increased the the following limits in php.ini:

```
max_input_time = 600000;
max_execution_time = 60000000;
file_uploads = On;
upload_max_filesize = 1000M;
post_max_size = 1000M;
and also in mysql.ini file i have changed
max_allowed_packet = 100M;
```

but still I get the following warning. Files less than 8mb are easily uploaded but greater than 8mb pops up the above error message.

Comment: after a change in php ini you should restart your web server

Comment: memory_limit = 16M add this code in your php.ini file and restart server @user3487726

Comment: I have restarted my server several times ,I have even restarted my computer but still the problem exists.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```

And then you should `stop your apache service and then start your apache`.

In case of linux based systems

```
/opt/lampp/lampp stop

/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

In case of windows just stop and stop your apache or your xampp service.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [phpinfo](https://www.php.net/phpinfo) page and see you have edited the correct configuration file. Loaded configuration file can be found in `phpinfo` page under `Loaded Configuration File`

Answer (score 0):

Add as first line at your process file 
set_time_limit(0);